# Find the distribution with the following Laplace transform.

Tags: probability, laplace-transform

Is anybody aware of the distribution whose Laplace transform is the following.

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[e^{-tX}] = \frac{e^{-t}}{(1+2t)}
\end{equation}

Note: The Laplace transform of the indicator random variable is $e^{-t}$ and of exponential distribution with mean $1/2$ is $\frac{1}{1+2t}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to compute a convolution. If $X$ is a random variable having pdf: $$ f_X(x) = \frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{1-x}{2}}\cdot \mathbb{1}_{[1,+\infty)}(x) $$
then, for every $t>-\frac{1}{2}$,
$$ \mathbb{E}[e^{-tX}]=\frac{e^{-t}}{1+2t} $$
as wanted.

Comment: So basically, it is a shifted exponential?

Comment: @user2808118: yes, exactly.